# Randomize array by groups in powershell

Tags: powershell

I randomize array like this in PS,

```
$array = "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"
$array | sort{get-random}
```

And I want randomize it by groups with 2 items, like this

(1st group)

a

c

(2nd group)

d

b

(items which out)

e

Comment: You `group` elements in an array based on certain conditions. Are you sure you just want to `get-random` elements. You can do this `Get-Random -InputObject $array -Count 2`. You will get random elements in group of 2, but I highly doubt that will serve any purpose. Else you can try `Group-Object` cmdlet, if you are grouping based on certain conditions..

Comment: Are you trying to randomize the groups or the items in each group?

Comment: randomize items in each group, or randomize array then make groups